# Extracting NMEA outputs from external bluetooth GPS to Android device

Tags: gps, android, nmea

I am requested to create an Android app that have to connect to an external Bluetooth GPS and read the NMEA output and visualize the location on ad digital map. I am a newcomer in this aspect.

How can I connect the GPS and read the NMEA file?

Can you suggest any good reference materials / source code?

I am instructed to simply import the coordinates from the non-professional grade GPS receiver (i.e. GoPass GPT-810 Bluetooth GPS Trip Recorder) and visualize them on top of a geotiff.

How can the android "locationlistener" get the coordinates from the GNSS receiver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve used the [Bluetooth GPS app from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=googoo.android.btgps&hl=en) to connect an android tablet to an external NMEA GPS over Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this (create an Android app that have to connect to an external Bluetooth GPS and read the NMEA output) for a professional-grade RTK/GNSS receiver, I recommend using [Lefebure NTRIP Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lefebure.ntripclient&hl=en). As well as providing a software-based NTRIP client to perform the RTK corrections, it injects the results into the Android Location Manager using Mock Locations. The additional RTK/GNSS parameters (e.g. PDOP, 3DRMS, Diff ID) are passed in the [location extras bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getExtras()). Since it is able to run in the background as a service, this allows your Android app to outsource handling of the Bluetooth connectivity/NMEA parsing/NTRIP, and simply read the final corrected values.

Answer (score 0):

It would likely depend on the GNSS hardware device. Some may be designed to start streaming NMEA via the bluetooth port on startup, more professional grade units (Leica, Trimble, Topcon, etc.) there will be a software application on the device to configure real-time settings, like correction source, NMEA sentences, etc.

What is the GNSS unit? Does it have a manual to tell you which NMEA sentences are being provided? NMEA is a standard, you can find more info on the format and data provided here: http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm